# auth0: update user roles using v2 api

Tags: auth0

I can use `https://xxx.au.auth0.com/api/v2/` to query and update the user. However not sur how to create roles and assign them to user.

Any idea please?

Comment: Hope you found what you were looking for. Have put an answer below that should do what you need. If you still have any issues, please just leave me comments below the answer and I shall try to assist.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do this is in [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) is with [Rules](https://auth0.com/docs/rules) - whereby you add the Roles information to the User Profile app_metadata attribute.

For example, here is a simple example

```
function addRolesToUser(user, context, callback) {   

  // ignore this rule if not correct client id of application using Rules 
  if (context.clientID !== 'eTQbNn3qxxxxxxxxxxxL6R7M7MDh') {
    return callback(null, user, context);
  }

  user.app_metadata = user.app_metadata || {};
  user.user_metadata = user.user_metadata || {};

  // You can add a Role based on what you want
  // In this case I check domain - give gmail ADMIN role
  var addRolesToUser = function (user, cb) {
    if (user.email.indexOf('@gmail.com') > -1) {
      cb(null, ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_USER']);
    } else {
      cb(null, ['ROLE_USER']);
    }
  };

  addRolesToUser(user, function (err, roles) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      user.app_metadata.roles = roles;
      auth0.users.updateAppMetadata(user.user_id, user.app_metadata)
        .then(function () {
          callback(null, user, context);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
          callback(err);
        });
    }
  });
}
```

The Roles are now part of the [User Profile](https://auth0.com/docs/user-profile) and available in the app_metadata for inspection. If you additionally want the Roles information to appear in the returned JWT ID Token, just add the `roles` scope to your authentication request.